# connection problem after downloading PostgresSQL12 version

Tags: postgresql-12

I have been running into this error ever since i downloaded the PostgresSQL 12 version 4.

> This site can’t be reached. The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:1/?key=05f10f64-fd3d-4747-bd68-47ef0e53e7a8 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, there's not enough information here. You haven't shared anything about your code. Also: have you verified your database instance is running? Without more details, there's really no way to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks David, I have started an course in Udemy, the Master Class on SQL which required me to download the PostgreSQL 12 , after the installation, while running the pgAdmin4 to connect , the above page opens up with the error.

Comment: Doesn't it sound like this one: https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports Using port 1 btw is pretty strange...

Comment: This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://127.0.0.1:1/?key=86340bf7-3c14-42f2-bc49-e254def5fead might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT    -------------- am still hitting the same error.